# Shortest distance between two words in the list

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a list of words and two words `word1` and `word2`, return the shortest distance between these two words in the list.

Example: given words = `["practice","makes","perfect","coding","makes"]`

- Input: word1 = "coding", word2 = "practice"
- Output: 3

We assume `word1` does not equal to `word2`, and both are in the list. List can be big as length 1000.

```
public int shortestDistance(String[]words, String word1, String word2){
 int temp = 0;

 if(word1.equals(words[words.length - 1])) && word2.equals(words[words.length - 2])||
    word2.equals(words[words.length - 1])) && word1.equals(words[words.length - 2]){
   return 1;
 }

 for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
   if(word1.equals(words[I]) || word2.equals(words[I])) && (temp == 0){
     temp++
   }else if(word1.equals(words[I]) || word2.equals(words[I])){
     return temp;
   }else if(temp > 0){
     temp++;
   }
 }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Code review is intended for working code only. Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: The code was taken from an image from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760567/shortest-distance-between-two-words-in-the-list I doubt OP is the author or he would have copied and pasted instead of typing it out. This is off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Care about final

Your parameters are never modified, so it is good practice to mark them `final`. Probably the method too, unless you expect it can be overridden.

```
public final int shortestDistance(final String[] words, final String word1, final String word2)
```

### Compare by indices

Instead of your `for` loop, you can use the indices of the elements.

```
public final int shortestDistance(final String[] words, final String word1, final String word2) {
   final List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList(words);

  final int word1Index = wordsList.indexOf(word1);
  final int word2Index = wordsList.indexOf(word2);

  return Math.abs(word2Index - word1Index);
}
```

### There could be duplicates

We can solve this problem by finding the index of each occurrence. The final product:

```
public final int shortestDistance(final String[] words, final String word1, final String word2) {
  final List<Integer> word1Indices = IntStream.range(0, words.length).boxed().filter(i -> words[i].equals(word1)).toList();
  final List<Integer> word2Indices = IntStream.range(0, words.length).boxed().filter(i -> words[i].equals(word2)).toList();

  int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  // Better way to do this but I'm tired.
  for(final Integer word1Index : word1Indices) {
    for(final Integer word2Index : word2Indices) result = Math.min(result, Math.abs(word2Index - word1Index));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid answering off-topic questions.

Comment: This would be a good answer if the question itself was on topic.